# How to format a number to a string in Scala

Tags: scala, formatting

How can I format a floating variable like `%6.2f` would do in `printf` (C) and store the result in a `string` variable?

Comment: Please first read some tutorials: https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/string-interpolation.html

Answer (score 3):

Here's a floating point (`Double`) value and a handful of `String` format options via string interpolation.

```
val d = 12345.678

f"|$d%f|${-d}%f|"             // |12345.678000|-12345.678000|
f"|$d%+f|${-d}%+f|"           // |+12345,678000|-12345,678000|
f"|$d% f|${-d}% f|"           // | 12345,678000|-12345,678000|
f"|$d%.2f|${-d}%.2f|"         // |12345,68|-12345,68|
f"|$d%,.2f|${-d}%,.2f|"       // |12,345.68|-12,345.68|
f"|$d%.2f|${-d}%(.2f|"        // |12345,68|(12345,68)|
f"|$d%10.2f|${-d}%10.2f|"     // |  12345,68| –12345,68|
f"|$d%010.2f|${-d}%010.2f|"   // |0012345,68|-012345,68|
```